# A more efficient way to convert XML to array of records using jquery?

Tags: jquery, find, each

I want to convert the following XML into an array of records:

```
<messages>
  <message>
    <id>1653</id>
    <text>AAA</text>
  </message>
  <message>
    <id>1659</id>
    <text>BBB</text>
  </message>
  <message>
    <id>1681</id>
    <text>CCC</text>
  </message>
</messages>
```

I have a query solution (below) that doesn't feel very efficient. Seems like I shouldn't have to

(1) resort to doing another `find` inside the `each()` loop, and

(2) have to wrap `this` with `$` all over again.  Is there a better way?

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(sXml);

var a = [];
var test = $(xmlDoc).find('message').each(function(index, xmlRec) {
    a.push({
        id: $(this).find('id').text(),
        text: $(this).find('text').text()
    })
})
```

Check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iPJxLyw6Qu7DeuM7nJCE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your points are absolutely fine, and there is nothing you can do to change them. The only improvement I would suggest is to use `map()` to create the array instead of `each()` and to cache the current node to avoid repeating `$(this)`:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(sXml);
var a = $(xmlDoc).find('message').map(function() {
    var $node = $(this);
    return {
        id: $node.find('id').text(),
        text: $node.find('text').text()
    };
}).get();
```